# Cannot WriteFile to a volume in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntfs, writefile

I am having some trouble with the `WriteFile` function in **C**.

I open a handle to the volume T: with `CreateFile`:

```
HANDLE hvol = CreateFile("\\\\.\\T:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 3,
                  NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Set the file pointer with `SetFilePointer`:

```
DWORD offset = SetFilePointer(hvol, bps + datarunOffset[0], NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

And write with:

```
bool wsuccess = WriteFile(hvol, filearray, secfilesize, &byteswritten, NULL);
```

Where `filearray` is an array of the byte values of a small file, and `secfilesize` is the number of elements in `filearray` rounded to a multiple of the disk's sector size (512).

If I have set the file pointer to **0x400** (the second sector of **$Boot**) then the array is written with no error codes.

If I have set the file pointer to **0x3200** (the second sector of **$UpCase**) then nothing is written and

> error code 5: access denied

is returned.

I cannot find a solution and I have full control over the volume. It just seemed odd that I could write to **$Boot** but not **$UpCase**, is there any reason for this? and can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Look at the MSDN article for WriteFile(), it talks about the need to use FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME.

Comment: Hey Hans, that's exactly what I was looking for. Works a treat, thanks.

Comment: Then please write an answer to your post, showing your solution. Then accept the answer. Thanks.